# getting stacktrace with context to thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I am trying to get the current stack-trace of a Thread in Java.  I have explored the following methods:

1. One of the easiest way of printing stack trace of current thread in Java is by using dumpStack()  method from java.lang.Thread class
2. Another way printing stack trace is using printStackTrace() method of Throwable class

Is there any other approach also by which we can get current stack trace  of thread in Java that is more efficient?

Below is the class That I have designed..

```
public class StackTraceExample 
{ 
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StringReplace.class.getName()); 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
 //calling a method to print stack trace further down 
first();
} 

public static void first()
{ 
second(); 
}

 private static void second() 
 {
 third();
 } 

 private static void third()
 {
 //If you want to print stack trace on console than use dumpStack() method 
  System.err.println("Stack trace of current thread using dumpStack() method");
  Thread.currentThread().dumpStack(); 

  //This is another way to print stack trace from current method 

  System.err.println("Printing stack trace using printStackTrace() method of Throwable "); 
  new Throwable().printStackTrace();

  //If you want stack trace as StackTraceElement in program itself than 
  //use getStackTrace() method of Thread class

  StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

  //Once you get StackTraceElement you can also print it to console 
  System.err.println("displaying Stack trace from StackTraceElement in Java");
  for(StackTraceElement st : stackTrace)
  {
  // System.err.println(st);
  } 
  }
  }
```

### output :-

```
Stack trace of current thread using dumpStack() method 
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace 
at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1249) 
at test.StringReplace.third(StringReplace.java:38) 
at test.StringReplace.second(StringReplace.java:31) 
at test.StringReplace.first(StringReplace.java:27)
at test.StringReplace.main(StringReplace.java:23)


Printing stack trace using printStackTrace() method of Throwable 
java.lang.Throwable
at test.StringReplace.third(StringReplace.java:42)
 at test.StringReplace.second(StringReplace.java:31)
 at test.StringReplace.first(StringReplace.java:27)
 at test.StringReplace.main(StringReplace.java:23) 
 displaying Stack trace from StackTraceElement in Java
```

Comment: Using `Thread.dumpStack` is pretty much exactly the same as creating an exception and printing it's stack trace. Internally, the `dumpStack` method just creates an exception and does what you are doing with your `Throwable`. Using `Thread.getStackTrace` will give you a lot more flexibility, as far as manipulating the returned information.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other approach also by which we can get current stack trace of thread in Java that is more efficient?

No.  The `thread.printStackTrace()` (or `getStackTrace()`) is the right way to go.  If it is the current thread then it uses an `Exception` internally but if it is another thread it generates the stack trace directly.

One thing to add is that if you want to get the stack trace of a thread but you are not sure you will use it, it should be more efficient to save an exception and then only call `getStackTrace()` when needed.  The stack trace is not fully fleshed out in the `Exception` until the call is made.  See the code for `Throwable.getOurStackTrace()` for more details.